# What can cause crypt to produce false validations?

Tags: php

I encountered a problem with a portal I am building, and decided to investigate further with a small stress test. This test, produced 4,000/10,000/50,000 different salts for one specified password. The code follows:

```
$Incline = 0;
$Max = 4000;
    $Auth = new Authentication();
    $FalseCounter = 0;
    $TrueCounter = 0;
while ($Incline < $Max){
            $PasswordString = "1";
        $Encrypted_Pass = $Auth->Hash_Password($PasswordString);
        $Check = crypt($PasswordString,$Encrypted_Pass['Salt']);

        if ($Check === $Encrypted_Pass['Password']){
            $TrueCounter++;
        }else{
            $FalseCounter++;
        }
    if ($Incline === $Max){
        break;
    }
    $Incline++;
}

echo 'Of '.$Max.' Checks '.$FalseCounter.' False Returns & '.$TrueCounter.' True Returns';
```

With `$Auth->Hash_Password` being:

```
public $Salt = null;
public function SetSalt(){
    $ByteSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
    $Salt = mcrypt_create_iv($ByteSize, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
    $this->Salt = $Salt;
    if (!is_null($this->Salt)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public function Hash_Password($Password){
    $this->SetSalt();
    $Return_Array = array();
    $Return_Array['Salt'] = $this->Salt;
    $Return_Array['Password'] = crypt($Password,$this->Salt);
    return $Return_Array;
}
```

Now, after showing the code. My output is as follows (on multiple refreshes)

> 1. Of 4000 Checks 22 False Returns & 3978 True Returns
> 2. Of 4000 Checks 15 False Returns & 3985 True Returns
> 3. Of 4000 Checks 15 False Returns & 3985 True Returns
> 4. Of 4000 Checks 10 False Returns & 3990 True Returns
> 5. Of 4000 Checks 6 False Returns & 3994 True Returns
> 6. Of 10000 Checks 40 False Returns & 9960 True Returns
> 7. Of 10000 Checks 43 False Returns & 9957 True Returns
> 8. Of 50000 Checks 196 False Returns & 49804 True Returns

Despite being a minute fail rate. The problem is still there. Regarding password encryption, Should this not be 100% for all password comparisons?

So, overall question is: What could cause this type of affect? Could it possibly be my coding? Or a flaw within the completely flawless PHP?

Comment: @ryanvincent whilst yes this is a solution to the problem as password_hash is more reliable.  The problem is that it is a very very slow method to use.. Unfortunately this doesn't answer my question to why the failures take place

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems crypt is affected by "null byte poisoning". All tests will pass, If you change your SetSalt method to this:

```
<?php
public function SetSalt()
{
    $ByteSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
    do {
        $Salt = mcrypt_create_iv($ByteSize, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);

        // Remove null byte from salt
        $this->Salt = str_replace(chr(0), '', $Salt);

    } while ($this->Salt !== $Salt); // Retry until salt without null byte is generated

    if (!is_null($this->Salt)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

After that all tests pass:

```
$ php crypt_test.php
Of 4000 Checks 0 False Returns & 4000 True Returns
```

If you want to read more about null bytes you can start here: http://www.madirish.net/401

For better illustration, here is an example output of a failing test:

```
string(34) "$1$iyJhOmt2$23uOXEcjWr2GcjSMqKpHk0"
array(2) {
  'Salt' =>
  string(16) "\000g-Ŕ=(
                       ��A��n0"
  'Password' =>
  string(34) "$1$QCbFiEDR$g3RDS7LK3m88K7XPqjF5O."
}
```

You can see the null byte here: `\0`.

And for all lazy people out there, here is the complete (fixed) test script I used ;)

```
<?php

class Authentication
{
    public $Salt = null;

    public function SetSalt()
    {
        $ByteSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
        do {
            $Salt = mcrypt_create_iv($ByteSize, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);

            // Remove null byte from salt
            $this->Salt = str_replace(chr(0), '', $Salt);
        } while ($this->Salt !== $Salt);

        if (!is_null($this->Salt)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function Hash_Password($Password)
    {
        $this->SetSalt();
        $Return_Array = array();
        $Return_Array['Salt'] = $this->Salt;
        $Return_Array['Password'] = crypt($Password, $this->Salt);
        return $Return_Array;
    }
}


$Incline = 0;
$Max = 4000;
$Auth = new Authentication();
$FalseCounter = 0;
$TrueCounter = 0;
while ($Incline < $Max) {
    $PasswordString = "1";
    $Encrypted_Pass = $Auth->Hash_Password($PasswordString);
    $Check = crypt($PasswordString, $Encrypted_Pass['Salt']);

    if ($Check === $Encrypted_Pass['Password']) {
        $TrueCounter++;
    } else {
        var_dump($Encrypted_Pass, $Check);
        $FalseCounter++;
    }
    if ($Incline === $Max) {
        break;
    }
    $Incline++;
}

echo 'Of ' . $Max . ' Checks ' . $FalseCounter . ' False Returns & ' . $TrueCounter . ' True Returns' . "\n";
```

Happy coding

Comment: Shouldn't the loop condition be `$this->Salt !== $Salt`?

Comment: More or less, both work as expected. With '$this->Salt !== $Salt' the performance should be better. So I will update my code.

Comment: Actually I don't know why this works with `===` operator. To my understanding this pice of code should provide a salt **without** the `null byte`, and the `===` actually causes to find one **with**.

Comment: @MaciejSz: This is a funny mistake I made. My first version generates salts until it find one with a null byte and use it. This works because the null byte is removed from the salt, but it has many iterations. Btw thanks for your hint ;)

Comment: Ohhh that's right! It worked because you assigned the return value of `str_replace` (I wish languages would be more functional to avoid this kind of overlooks). Now it's clear! Anyway, glad I could help. And btw: nice catch with the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I left the bounty open to see other views on this situation and to attract more attention.  The solution works great and the explanation is more than adequate. I never considered the possibility of null byte poisioning. Since reading this solution.  It has helped me get across the user authentication problem and continue with the development of the project. Seriously.  Thank you so much for the response and depth of your answer. Just wish I offered a higher bounty if I had known I'd get this response.. once again, thank you

Comment: @DarylGill with your comment, you made my day. Such an comment is more worth than a higher bounty :) I'm glad i could held.